# override the chart legend. how?

Tags: javascript, dojo, charts, dojox.charting

normally we made something like this, and the update have the same name.

```
    chart1.addSeries("job", new, {

    });
```

it is possible to override the series job, with another name, for example override the series job with the series "something"? when i make the update?

the problem is, if i make the update with the same name only the values of the series is changed, but the chart legend is the same

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the existing series (`chart.removeSeries('job')`), and add the new series with the same name (`chart.addSeries('job')`). Also we can do the same for the legend.